# Can I Ask a Question That Seeks Answers For A Possibility To Do Something

Tags: discussion

I want to ask 'Can I Upload An Image on Facebook Page by Providing Image URL Using PHP SDK v5"?

It should be posted an image with a caption and not a link.

Comment: The answer would be, "Probably, but it depends on the limitations of the API."  That's not a very good answer IMO, since it would force others to read the API as opposed to you reading it first.  Now, if you have read it, and found a call in the API that does what you want, but you're having difficulties with it, *then* you should ask a question.  Bear in mind, the question can't just be, "It's not working"; you would have to provide a decent amount of information about *what* specifically wouldn't work with that *particular* API call.

Comment: "How can I ..?" is always better than "Can I..?".

Comment: Just to inform you guys, I recovered from -3 votes to +1 votes. Faith on meta.stackoverflow.com users increased! :-) I thought this question is going to be deleted soon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A question like this may not be well received, because with that minimal amount of information, it looks like you're asking for someone else to read the documentation for you and summarize this one bit of information you need. In other words, it sounds like you just didn't feel like reading the docs, and are hoping that someone else will do that work for you.

But if done well, it could probably be a good question.

Does the SDK's documentation suggest it can be done? If so, then we'd expect that you gave it a reasonable try before posting to Stack Overflow. If you did, and your attempt didn't work, then you should use the usual "best practices" to form the question: what did you try, what went wrong with it, what did you not understand about whatever error messages you saw, etc.

If you couldn't find anything in the documentation about whether or not it's possible, then those usual best practices still apply, just to the docs instead of to code. Instead of "what did you try?" it would be "which docs did you read; which similar APIs did you look at; were there any APIs that looked like they should have options to do this, but didn't?" etc. At minimum, this may help potential answers narrow down the scope of what they need to answer: they don't need to say "no, but there's a similar API at ___" if you note that API in your question, along with an explanation of why it isn't what you need. And let's factor in the human element, too: making it clear that you've done your research will probably ward away a lot of "didn't you read the docs?" downvotes.